# Can we prioratize 'defaultLocale' as first and than others?

Tags: next.js13, next-intl

Here's how locale detection is done,

Locale detection
The locale is detected based on these priorities:

1. A locale prefix is present in the pathname (e.g. /de/about)
2. A cookie is present that contains a previously detected locale
3. The accept-language header(opens in a new tab) is matched against the available locales
4. The defaultLocale is used

I want to use the **defaultLocale** set in middleware manually to always run first.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.